# Repeatedly read subprocess output with tokio-process

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

For a GUI tool I'm writing in Rust I'd like to kick off long-lived subprocesses and then repeatedly poll them for output. I don't want to block indefinitely waiting for output from any given one, so I'm using `tokio` and `tokio-process` to run the process and timeout the output reading. I need to store the subprocess in a struct as well.

I'm running into problems because it seems I need to consume the subprocess's output stream in order to read from it, so after a single read I'm unable to access it again.

I've included a simplified reproduction of my problem below. It prints actual output for the first invocation of `print_output`, but then prints `No process_output_fut` for the second invocation since I had to `take` the output future out of the `Plugin` struct and consume it in order to read from it.

Any suggestions for how to refactor this code to avoid consuming the process output future with each attempt to fetch the output?

```rust
extern crate tokio;

use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::codec::{FramedRead, LinesCodec};
use tokio::prelude::stream::StreamFuture;
use tokio::timer::Timeout;
use tokio_process::{Child, ChildStdout, CommandExt};

pub struct Plugin {
    process: Option<Child>,
    process_output_fut: Option<Timeout<StreamFuture<FramedRead<ChildStdout, LinesCodec>>>>,
    tokio_runtime: tokio::runtime::Runtime,
}

impl Plugin {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return Plugin {
            process: None,
            process_output_fut: None,
            tokio_runtime: tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().expect(
                "Could not create tokio runtime"
            ),
        }
    }

    pub fn spawn(&mut self, arg: String) {
        let mut process = Command::new("/bin/ls")
            .arg(arg)
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn_async()
            .expect("Failed to spawn command");

        if let Some(plugin_output) = process.stdout().take() {
            let lines_codec = LinesCodec::new();
            self.process_output_fut = Some(FramedRead::new(plugin_output, lines_codec)
                .into_future()
                .timeout(Duration::from_millis(3000)));
        }
        self.process = Some(process);
    }

    pub fn print_output(&mut self) {
        if let Some(process_output_fut) = self.process_output_fut.take() {
            let result = self.tokio_runtime.block_on(process_output_fut).unwrap();
            if let Some(output) = result.0 {
                    println!("{:?}", output);
            };
        } else {
            println!("No process_output_fut");
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut p = Plugin::new();
    p.spawn("/");
    p.print_output();
    p.print_output();
}
```

Comment: Here is some code which does something similar; hopefully it's useful! https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/blob/0234eceb2b3f215174a31cc47a36cccceddb8593/src/rust/engine/process_execution/src/local.rs#L90-L210

Comment: @DanielWagner-Hall thanks for the pointer! Does that code read the output stream repeatedly, or does it buffer it all up and read it at once still?

Comment: It does both: `StreamedHermeticCommand::stream` produces a stream of output, and then `ChildResults::collect_from` uses `fold` on that stream to read each chunk, waiting until the end, and join them together into single buffers per stream.